# Removing Order date from WooCommerce emails

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm trying to remove the order date from the woocommerce emails, but as I'm not that confident in PHP I'm finding myself a bit stuck.

Below is some code I've found to a similar question (instead removing the order number but leaving the date...I want to do the opposite.

```
<?php
// Targetting specific email notificatoins
$email_ids = array('new_order', 'customer_on_hold_order');

$date = sprintf( '<time datetime="%s">%s</time>', $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) );

// Displaying order number except for "New Order" and "Customer On Hold Order" notifications
if( ! in_array($email->id, $email_ids) ){
    $order_number = sprintf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_order_number() );
    $date = '('.$date.')';
} else {
    $date = __('Order date:', 'woocommerce') . ' ' . $date;
    $order_number = '';
}

if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
    $before = '<a class="link" href="' . esc_url( 

$order->get_edit_order_url() ) . '">';
        $after  = '</a> ';
    } else {
        $before = '';
        $after  = ' ';
    }
?>

<h2><?php echo $before . $order_number . $after . $date; ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure this one out myself...(although not sure it's good practice...but it works!)

Simply added a class to the h2 tag within your-child-theme/woocommerce/emails/email-order-details.php, like below:

```
<h2 class="fbc-time">
<?php
if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
    $before = '<a class="link" href="' . esc_url( $order->get_edit_order_url() ) . '">';
    $after  = '</a>';
} else {
    $before = '';
    $after  = '';
}
/* translators: %s: Order ID. */
echo wp_kses_post( $before . sprintf( __( 'Order #%s', 'woocommerce' ) . $after . ' <time datetime="%s">%s</time>', $order->get_order_number(), $order->get_date_created()->format( 'c' ), wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ) );
?>
```

Then selected the class in email-styles.php and used display: none